# MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED when returning from a phone call on API 23 but not 27

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager, android-mediasession

I have to maintain an app that uses `MediaSessionCompat` and a `MediaPlayer` to stream audio files from a server.

There is a bug that I've reproduced on a Pixel XL and Nexus 5 (API 23) that doesn't happen on the same devices running (API 27).  I've heard a report of an XL user running API 28 experiencing it as well.

When a phone call comes in, the app can't duck it so we pause.  On API 27, the call ends, the app gets audio focus, and we start playing again.  On API 23 (and 28?  I haven't confirmed), as soon as the call ends the Media Server crashes with error 100 (`MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED`).  Reliably crashes, every time the call ends.

I can't make heads or tails of it.

Does anyone know why it's fine on 27 but not on 23 or what I can do to prevent the crash (rather than attempting to start everything back up after the crash)?

The stack trace looks like this

`10-31 17:36:04.499 8062-8074/? A/AudioTrackShared: Assertion failed: buffer == NULL || buffer->mFrameCount == 0
10-31 17:36:04.499 8062-8074/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8074 (FastMixer)
10-31 17:36:04.500 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-31 17:36:04.500 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:6.0/MASTER/5056751:userdebug/test-keys'
10-31 17:36:04.500 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
10-31 17:36:04.500 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
10-31 17:36:04.500 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG: pid: 8062, tid: 8074, name: FastMixer  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
10-31 17:36:04.500 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
10-31 17:36:04.500 1639-1727/system_process W/NativeCrashListener: Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 8062
10-31 17:36:04.502 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'Assertion failed: buffer == NULL || buffer->mFrameCount == 0'
10-31 17:36:04.502 1362-1362/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
10-31 17:36:04.502 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 00001f7e  ecx 00001f8a  edx 00000006
10-31 17:36:04.502 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     esi b427f980  edi 00000000
10-31 17:36:04.502 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
10-31 17:36:04.502 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     eip b6fb7f56  ebp 00001f8a  esp b427ee80  flags 00200206
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00083f56  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+22)
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000815e8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+70)
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00027205  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+36)
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000209e4  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+80)
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000cbc3  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+128)
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0008353d  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::ServerProxy::obtainBuffer(android::Proxy::Buffer*, bool)+669)
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00053af7  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00066155  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0002630a  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00026d42  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00025e93  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0006c19a  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0006d88f  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00014aac  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+418)
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 000141cf  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+122)
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 00080a93  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+56)
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00021952  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+25)
10-31 17:36:04.504 1362-1362/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 000170b6  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)`